# How to get rid of long calls in this() constructor?

Tags: java, oop

The constructor call in one of my classes looks like this:

```
API() {
    this(
        (new Client.ClientBuilder(AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getA(),
                     AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getBt()))
                    .withF(YetAnotherClass.class).build(),
        (new Client.ClientBuilder(AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getA(),
                    AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getB())
                    .withE(AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getC())
                    .withD(AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getD())).build(),
        (new Client.ClientBuilder(
                    AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getA(),
                    AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getB())
                    .withY(AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).build()
        );
    }
```

In reality, it's even worse, since I obfuscated class and method names.

I am using a Builder pattern to generate a client and my first idea was to first generate the three clients, and then pass the variables in the constructor call.

However, since this takes place in a constructor, the call to this has to be the first statement. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Maybe separate out an `addClient()` method that can be called as many times as it needs to be.  In this case 3.  At least the `API` object would be through its `init` phase

Comment: Well, it makes totally sense :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only immediate option I see: create small helper methods that do **parts** of the construction, like:

```
private AnotherClass makeAnotherClass() {
  return new Client.ClientBuilder(AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getA(),
    AnotherClas.get(YetAnotherClass.class).getBt()))
    .withF(YetAnotherClass.class).build());
```

If there is no way to get **rid** of the complexity, then at least transform it into a "format" that is easier to digest.

And the above is easier - as you reduced the number lines required. This means that your brain can much easier create a "context" in which to "embed" code. This might sound like a small thing - but our brains are doing this constantly. They try to abstract in order to create "sense" and to "classify". Therefore a set of well named small methods is simply better compared to having the same content within one method.

And of course, you can now change your constructor call to something like

```
this(makeAnotherClass(), makeYetAnotherClass() ...
```

Yes, this creates "overhead" as you now have more methods; and they are probably called only once. But still: it allows you to uphold the [Single Layer of Abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principle. And following this principle definitely improves the readability of your code.